# Deploying war file to artifactory from jenkins using grails

Tags: grails, jenkins, artifactory

I need to deploy war file in to artifactory, i was able to deploy war file to specific repo but i want to deploy it with groupid,version id and artifactID. How do i do the configuration for the GAV's in jenkins to publish the war file artifactory.we dont have pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `pom.xml` by using the [`create-pom`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-pom.html) target

```
grails create-pom [group-id]
```

And then modify the `pom.xml` according this [blog post](http://blog.chintoju.com/2012/12/deploy-to-artifactory-remote-repository-using-maven.html). Now `Jenkins` can use `Maven` to deploy your war file.